# Amchart 4: How to highlight bar/column on click of bar/column in bar plots

Tags: javascript, bar-chart, amcharts4

I am trying to highlight the bar/column on click of bar/column in Amchart 4. Using the below code, I am getting the value of current clicked bar/column but using the `column.isActive` property, the bar/column is not getting highlighted.

I found this [Amchart official Documentation](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/highlighting-column-on-axis-label-click/) link, but it is about on click of axis label. I am trying to implement the same but on click of bar/column, not axis label.

This is the code implementation:

```
am4core.ready(function() {

// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [{
  "country": "USA",
  "visits": 2025
}, {
  "country": "China",
  "visits": 1882
}, {
  "country": "Japan",
  "visits": 1809
}, {
  "country": "Germany",
  "visits": 1322
}, {
  "country": "UK",
  "visits": 1122
}];

// Create axes

var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "country";
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;

categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.adapter.add("dy", function(dy, target) {
  if (target.dataItem && target.dataItem.index & 2 == 2) {
    return dy + 25;
  }
  return dy;
});

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "visits";
series.dataFields.categoryX = "country";
series.name = "Visits";
series.columns.template.tooltipText = "{categoryX}: [bold]{valueY}[/]";
series.columns.template.fillOpacity = .8;

var columnTemplate = series.columns.template;
columnTemplate.strokeWidth = 2;
columnTemplate.strokeOpacity = 1;

// Make a panning cursor
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
chart.cursor.behavior = "panXY";
chart.cursor.snapToSeries = series;

chart.events.on("hit", function(ev){
 chart.series.each(function(series) {
     if (series instanceof am4charts.ColumnSeries) {
       series.columns.each(function(column) {
         if (column.dataItem.categories.categoryX == series.tooltipDataItem.dataContext.country) {           
           console.log(column.dataItem.categories.categoryX, series.tooltipDataItem.dataContext.country);
           column.isActive = true;
         } else {
           column.isActive = false;
         }
       })
     }
   })
})
}); // end am4core.ready()
```

Now, I also found this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49404094/highlight-a-single-bar-on-click-in-amcharts) post link, but that was related to the Amchart version 3 libraray and I am using Amchart 4.

Kindly check this [jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fgpox7wj/) implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not require the `hit` listener for this per definition, only if you want to deactivate other columns while activating the clicked one. You merely have to make the columns `togglable` and define the actual properties in *active* state.

### You have to make the columns togglable.

`series.columns.template.togglable = true;`

This will toggle the active state from `false` to `true`. [togglable](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/column/#togglable)

### Properties while state is active

```
var tActiveState = series.columns.template.states.create("active");
tActiveState.properties.strokeWidth = 0;
tActiveState.properties.fill = "crimson";
```

You have to set the properties of the active state. [states](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/states/)

### Deactivate other columns on hit

```
series.columns.template.events.on("hit", function(event){
  series.columns.each(function(column){
    if(column !== event.target){
      column.setState("default");
      column.isActive = false
    }
  })
});
```

For this we are to use the `hit` listener again. [Event Listeners](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/event-listeners/)

### Example based on your code

```js
am4core.ready(function() {
  // Themes begin
  am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
  // Themes end

  // Create chart instance
  var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

  // Add data
  chart.data = [{
    "country": "USA",
    "visits": 2025
  }, {
    "country": "China",
    "visits": 1882
  }, {
    "country": "Japan",
    "visits": 1809
  }, {
    "country": "Germany",
    "visits": 1322
  }, {
    "country": "UK",
    "visits": 1122
  }];

  // Create axes

  var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
  categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "country";
  categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
  categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;

  categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.adapter.add("dy", function(dy, target) {
    if (target.dataItem && target.dataItem.index & 2 == 2) {
      return dy + 25;
    }
    return dy;
  });

  var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

  // Create series
  var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
  series.dataFields.valueY = "visits";
  series.dataFields.categoryX = "country";
  series.name = "Visits";
  series.columns.template.tooltipText = "{categoryX}: [bold]{valueY}[/]";
  series.columns.template.fillOpacity = .8;

  //REM: Making the columns togglable.
  series.columns.template.togglable = true;

  //REM: Setting the properties of the "hover" state
  var tHoverState = series.columns.template.states.create("hover");
  tHoverState.properties.strokeWidth = 1;
  tHoverState.properties.fill = "yellow";

  //REM: Setting the properties of the active state "isActive=true"
  var tActiveState = series.columns.template.states.create("active");
  tActiveState.properties.strokeWidth = 0;
  tActiveState.properties.fill = "crimson";

  var columnTemplate = series.columns.template;
  columnTemplate.strokeWidth = 2;
  columnTemplate.strokeOpacity = 1;

  // Make a panning cursor
  chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
  chart.cursor.behavior = "panXY";
  chart.cursor.snapToSeries = series;

  //REM: To deactivate other columns on click
  series.columns.template.events.on("hit", function(event){
    series.columns.each(function(column){
      if(column !== event.target){
        column.setState("default");
        column.isActive = false
      }
    })
  });

}); // end am4core.ready()
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>

<div id = 'chartdiv'></div>
```

### Alternatively you can skip togglable and only use hit

```
series.columns.template.events.on("hit", function(event){
  series.columns.each(function(column){
    //REM: Deactivate all non clicked columns
    if(column !== event.target){
      column.setState("default");
      column.isActive = false
    }
    //REM: Toggle the clicked column
    else{
      column.isActive = !column.isActive
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: What a beautiful answer. Used my last upvote of the day.

Comment: Great man. Thanks for the help. I really appreciate.

Comment: In next 6 hours, I'll award you the bounty. Anyway, if you know how to combine two amchart graphs into one then let me know. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61682646/trying-to-combine-two-amcharts-graphs-but-getting-data-fields-for-series-are-n

Comment: Sadly I am mostly still stuck on V3 myself, if I find time during the weekend I shall take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if amchart has api for it or not, but because it's based on svg, we can easily set style for selected column like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lt8fd64/2/)

```
column.element.node.parentNode.setAttribute('fill', highLightColor);           
column.element.node.parentNode.setAttribute('stroke', highLightStrokeColor);
```